# How to get a div object on top

Tags: php, css, html

I'm using the following code

```
<?php
$link= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo "<div id='link' style='position: relative; margin: 60 auto; width: 70%; top: -10px;
height: 100%;'>{$link}";

?>
```

The code works fine but I have other content on the page. This makes the above code move my content down the page or up depending on how I set up the margin.

What I want to do is to have my echo text to appear over my content.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use position:absolute;

```
<?php
$link= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo "<div id='link' style='position: absolute; width: 70%; top: 0px;
height: 100%;'>{$link}</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks V413HAV but it is still dragging my content

Comment: @CongoleseMedia don't use margin

Comment: @CongoleseMedia close your </div>

Comment: Thanks  V413HA The problem occurred because I forgot to add the closing div tag

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet here is to use position: absolute instead of relative.  Push the rest of the content down some with a margin if you need to adjust it's spacing compared to the div.

Make sure to set a left: and top: attribute to ensure cross-browser consistency.